# Use ng-repeat with Arrays Nested in an Array

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have a json file that I'm getting with

```
$scope.load = function() {
        var httpRequest = $http.get('json/properties.json')
            .then(function(res) {
                $scope.properties = res.data;
            });
    };
```

The Json file is something like:

```
        [{
        "property": "address",
        "options": ["zipCode", "city", "cityPrefix", "citySuffix", "streetName", "streetAddress", "streetSuffix", "streetPrefix", "secondaryAddress", "county", "country", "countryCode", "state", "stateAbbr", "latitude", "longitude"]
    }, {
        "property": "commerce",
        "options": ["color", "department", "productName", "price", "productAdjective", "productMaterial", "product"]
    }, {
        "property": "company",
        "options": ["suffixes", "companyName", "companySuffix", "catchPhrase", "bs", "catchPhraseAdjective", "catchPhraseDescriptor", "catchPhraseNoun", "bsAdjective", "bsBuzz", "bsNoun"]
    }]
```

and I have this HTML:

```html
<div ng-repeat="(property, options) in properties ">
  <p>{{property}} - {{options}}</p>
</div>
```

For each entry in my JSON array, I want to create a list with the "property" value and inside this list an li with each "option" of this property but for some reason the closest I got to was having 15 (?) lists for each property.
Any help? 

[EDIT]

[Link to current github repository](https://github.com/davidRibeiro/angular-faker)

Answer (score 2):

Right from the [AngularJS ng-repeat duplicate error docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes):

```
<div ng-repeat="(property, options) in properties track by $index">
   <p>{{property}} - {{options}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work, I added the github repository, maybe I'm not explaining my problem very well, or maybe my problem is not is this part of the project

Answer (score 0):

I think using track by $index  will work.

```html
<div ng-repeat="(property, options) in properties track by $index">
          <p>{{property}} - </p>
          <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="option in options track by $index">{{option}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Didn't work, I added the github repository, maybe I'm not explaining my problem very well, or maybe my problem is not is this part of the project